# Domain controller and local computer different timezones for automatic updates

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, automatic-updates

If the Windows domain controller is in PST time zone and the local computer is in the EST time zone and automatic updates are scheduled for 1:00 AM via group policy, will the local computer install them at 1:00 AM EST or 4:00 AM EST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client computer will install updates at 1:00 AM in it's timezone.